# Protobuf3: Serialize a Python object to JSON

Tags: python, json, serialization, protocol-buffers-3

According to [the manual](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0), Protobuf 3.0.0 supports JSON serialization:

> A well-defined encoding in JSON as an alternative to binary proto encoding.

**What have I tried**

- `json.dumps(instance)` which raised `TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")`
- Looked for a `instance.to_json()` (or alike) function
- Searched the Python docs

**How do I serialize a Python proto object to JSON?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function `MessageToJson` in the `json_format` module. This function can be used to serialize the message.

Comment: Thanks. Just found out about it (see my own answer). My problem was elsewhere, in the package installation (installed the wrong one).

Answer (score 7):

## Caveats

I have mistakingly installed `protobuf3` - I thought it the, well, `protobuf3` Python package, but it's an unofficial **Python 3 protobuf 2 package**, not the other way around. Remove it before you start.

## Solution

After some trial and error, the following solution works. Feel free to post better / official ones if you have any.

### Prerequisite: Protobuf 3

- Remove `protobuf2` (I used `brew uninstall`). Make sure `protoc` does not appear in the path.
- Install the [`protobuf3`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0) binaries. There is no homebrew package yet, so I used OSX binaries `protoc-3.0.0-osx-x86_64.zip`. The `make` script is also an option.

  - Copy the content of the `bin` directory to `/usr/local/bin`
  - Copy the content of the `include` to `/usr/local/include`
- Make sure protobuf3 is installed - `protoc --version` should show `libprotoc 3.0.0`.

### Python installation

- Create a virtual environment
- Download the [master branch of `protobuf`](https://github.com/google/protobuf) to `/tmp`
- Activate the virtual environment
- `cd protobuf-master/python && setup.py install`

### Code

The relevant function is `MessageToJson` in the `google.protobuf.json_format module`:

```
from google.protobuf import json_format
o = SomeProtobufClass()
print json_format.MessageToJson(o)
{
...
}
```

Comment: And `MessageToDict` is often a handy sidekick to `MessageToJson`!